# In Pico CMS content markdown file how to define an array

Tags: php, twig, yaml

In my simple Pico (0.9) based website I would like to add category pages that would list a set of objects, different for each category and defined in the markdown file for each category. In theory it should then be possible to list them in the twig template using the `{% for object in set %}` syntax.

I have happily been getting my own variables from the `.md` files using my own plugin which maps my custom `Key Value Pair Label:` onto a custom field in the `meta` variable in the template. But I just cannot get it to work with arrays.

Apparently the markdown header uses YAML and I have read the specification for that and there are a number of ways to specify such a list. So I have tried things like...

```
/*
Title: Example Category Page - Cutlery
My Items: ['fork', 'spoon', 'knife']
*/
```

Or this:

```
/*
Title: Example Category Page - Cutlery
My Items:
 - fork
 - spoon
 - knife
*/
```

But when this is loaded in the template (with my plugin mapping it to `meta.my_items`) with code like this:

```
{% for item in meta.my_items %}
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Nothing is displayed as if the array `meta.my_items` is empty.

Ideally I would want to expand the objects in the array from simple strings to a set of KVPs (title, image, description) which I should be able to do in YAML.

So my question is - is this actually supported in Pico CMS and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The YAML in both things your tried represents exactly the same structure only differing in style (flow vs. block) but not in semantics. If one doesn't work, trying the other is a waste of time.

Comment: While you are right in a perfect world - this isn't perfect. I disagree that trying things a different way is a waste of time, it may lead to insights and workarounds. Here's five problems that could be exposed... 1. User misconception of the syntax of one of the styles, 2. Subtle typo leads to syntax error, 3. Incorrect documentation for one of the styles, 4. Incomplete implementation of the standard by the YAML parser in use, 5. Bug in the YAML parser. Also, specifically for stackoverflow, it shows have done research prior to my question and won't get answers that I've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried (with the version 1.0) but the only working solution i found was about renaming it in the definition with an uderscore in the name. So try this:

```
My_Items: ['fork', 'spoon', 'knife']
```

instead of this:

```
My Items: ['fork', 'spoon', 'knife']
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I have found that upgrading to pico cms 1.0 makes this all possible. The syntax in the example by @Matteo works as does the  "dash and line delimited" style in the second example in my question. Not only this but I am also able to define list items with multiple fields, which is really useful. The upgrade has broken some things in my theme, but I am sure they can be fixed. Thanks.